# Android getContentLength() returns -1 when trying to download a dynamically created file

Tags: android, urlconnection

On an Android application I am working on I have to download and parse a file that I create at the time of request from the application. The file being requested is a php file that returns values from a database formatted for my application to parse. In the application I request getContentLength() so I can update the user on the status of the download. When requesting getContentLength() it returns -1. I have used this class before for static files on the server and it returns the appropriate information for the file. Wondering if someone had a workaround for this, so I can continue to update the user instead of just displaying "Loading..."

Comment: It returns this because your server is using [`Transfer-encoding: chunked`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), i.e. it does now know the length of the response. The only way to fix it is to fix the server side if you require Content-length to be set in your HTTP response.

Comment: Would <?php 

$length = ob_get_length(); 
header("Content-Length: $length"); 

?> work to return content-length to my application? Is there a way to return the content length using php?

Comment: yup, some variant of reading the output buffer length should do it.